# how to set 2 variables to either 1 or 0 based on a 3rd variables value

Tags: ruby

I have a variable that will have the following values:

```
blah = # 1, 0, or -1
```

Now I want to set these two variables:

```
up

down
```

To either 1 or 0 based on the value of 'blah'.

If blah is 1, then up = 1 and down = 0, if blah is -1 then down = 1 and up = 0

If blah is 0, then both are 0.

How can you do this the ruby way w/o so many if checks?

Comment: Is `up` ever anything other than 0?

Comment: According to this, up is always 0. Why would `up` be 0 when `blah` is `1`? **Edit** @Jordan got there first

Comment: What is `up` when `blah == -1`? What is `down` when `blah == 1`?

Comment: sorry fixed it above, blah represents the state, so 1 is up, -1 is down.  if its 1 then up=1, if its -1 then down=1

Comment: Your question is contradictory. How can blah be 0 when it is -1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution 1

```
up, down =
case blah
when 1; [1, 0]
when 0; [0, 0]
when -1; [0, 1]
end
```

Solution 2 (Inspired by mu is too short)

```
up, down = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]][blah]
```

Comment: @mu is too short Hi again. But isn't `blah <=> 0` equal to `blah`?

Comment: @mu is too short Since `blah` is also always -1, 0, or 1, I think @sawa is correct.

Comment: +1 for the second one. It's what I would have used. Its obscurity disappears after just a second of thinking to remember how an array works. It's going to be very fast.

Answer (score 3):

A variant of sawa's and SirDarius's that allows `blah` to be greater than, less than, or equal to zero rather than just -1, 0, or 1:

```
def mapper(x)
    h = {
        -1 => [0, 1],
         0 => [0, 0],
         1 => [1, 0]
    }
    h[x <=> 0]
end

up, down = mapper(blah)
```

Note that [Fixnum's `<=>` operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001092) is specified to return -1, 0, or 1 (or `nil` of course):

> Returns -1, 0, +1 or nil depending on whether fix is less than, equal to, or greater than numeric.

So using `<=>` is a safe way to implement the [signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) for Fixnum.

Answer (score 2):

According to your *initial* specification, the following code worked:

```
up = 0
down = -blah
```

EDIT:

Here is a creative way to achieve the desired result using a Hash:

```
states = { -1 => [0,1], 0 => [0,0], 1 => [1,0] }
up, down = states[blah]
```

Comment: that's a testament to why a good specification is necessary in software development :)

Answer (score 2):

```
up = blah == 1 ? 1 : 0
down = blah == -1 ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is ruby-specific... something like

```
up = blah != -1
down = blah != 1
```

I assume you mean that up should be 1 when blah is 1.

Comment: `!=` will return boolean, he wants integers

Comment: Ok, fine; so `up = (blah == -1 ? 0 : 1)`; `down = (blah == 1 ? 0 : 1)`. Although I'm not convinced that he **really** wants integers... what is the purpose of this exactly?

Comment: Honestly I wish I knew, he might want integers, but the spec is so vague

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it:

```
up, down = [0, blah].max, [0, -blah].max
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset both answers to 0 and then adjust as necessary

```
up, down = 0, 0
up = 1 if blah > 0
down = 1 if blah < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Integer
  def up?
    self == 1
  end

  def down?
    self == -1
  end
end

x = 1
x.up? # => true
```